# How to make exact copy (style and data) of MySQL pivot table to HTML?

Tags: php, html, mysql, pivot-table

Hi I've got the following pivot table from mysql database:

```
+----------------------------------------------------+------------------+------------------+
| km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_value_building_id | Tabella gruppo A | Tabella gruppo B |
+----------------------------------------------------+------------------+------------------+
|                                                 74 |          79.000  |         201.000  |
|                                                 75 |          26.000  |          32.000  |
|                                                 76 |          90.000  |           0.000  |
|                                                 77 |          98.000  |           0.000  |
|                                                 78 |          52.000  |          63.000  |
|                                                 79 |          55.000  |          67.000  |
|                                                 80 |          55.000  |          47.000  |
|                                                 81 |          58.000  |          49.000  |
|                                                 82 |          61.000  |          51.000  |
|                                                 83 |          64.000  |          53.000  |
|                                                 84 |          59.000  |          55.000  |
|                                                 85 |          62.000  |          59.000  |
|                                                 86 |          64.000  |          60.000  |
|                                                 87 |          62.000  |          58.000  |
|                                                 88 |          59.000  |         105.000  |
|                                                 89 |          56.000  |         100.000  |
+----------------------------------------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

I obtain it using the following stored procedure:

```sql
BEGIN
    SELECT

    GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT("MAX(IF(km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_value_table_id='", km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_value_table_id, "',km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_millesimal_value ,NULL)) AS '", km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_name, "'"), "
"
      )INTO @answers
    FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_value_table_id, km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_name FROM km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_values INNER JOIN km_kondomanager_millesimal_table
                 ON km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_values . km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_value_table_id = km_kondomanager_millesimal_table. km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_id WHERE km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_value_group_id = km_group
    ) A;

    SET @query := 
      CONCAT(
        'SELECT km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_value_building_id, ', @answers, 
        ' FROM km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_values WHERE km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_value_group_id = ',km_group,' GROUP BY km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_value_building_id'
      );

    PREPARE statement FROM @query;
    EXECUTE statement;
END
```

Where "km_group" is a **IN** parameter, the question is how can I call this stored procedure from `PHP` and build a `HTML` table that look **exactly the same** as the pivot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call [stored procedure](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/php-calling-mysql-stored-procedures/) from `PHP`, where 212 is `km_group` id

```
$records = mysqli_query( $con, 'CALL stored_procedure_name(212)' );
```

Then fetch and traverse through results like we do for usual mysql queries.